# Convert Plain Text File to Pipe-Delimited CSV file

Tags: powershell-3.0

I need to convert Plain / Flat Text file of thousands of rows on daily basis, I want to convert it to Pipe-delimited with powershell.

```
sample data
6790001009100044019161020140000000892200041962020100104810000000001CARD PAR                                          219293948539475161020111610201440000200
-first Pipe at 9
-second Pipe at 18
-third at 26
-fourth at 39
-fifth at 45
-sixth at 55
-seventh at 57
-eight at 67
-ninth at 117
-tenth at 157
```

`enter code here`

How do i convert this file to Pipe delimited file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Insert()` method. It'll insert characters into text on desired positions. There are other ways of doing that, for instance with `RegEx`.

```
$Positions=@(9,18,26,39,45,55,57,67,117,157)
$dat = '6790001009100044019161020140000000892200041962020100104810000000001CARD PAR                                          219293948539475161020111610201440000200'

$Positions | foreach {
    $dat=$dat.Insert($_,'|')
}
$dat
```

Keep in mind, that `Insert()` will fail if first parameter is bigger than text length.

Comment: Since $dat is re-evaluated on each time through the loop, the value of $Positions[] will be increasingly inaccurate with each iteration.  For example, run this: `$Positions=@(2,4,5,6,9)
$dat = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'

$Positions | foreach {
    $dat
    $dat=$dat.Insert($_,'|')
}
$dat`

Comment: @Number8 No, they won't. If you insert `|` at position 2, it'll stay at position 2 no matter what you insert after that. So you're fine as long as `$Positions` is sorted in ascending order. Another thing I should've mentioned is that `Insert` is 0-based.

Comment: @AL - The length of the string changes with each iteration of the foreach.  Unless you take that in to account when creating the Positions array, you won't get the results you expect.

Comment: @Number8 I assume that question owner wants to see the result with pipes at given positions. To do it your way, it only requires to sort `$Positions` in descending order. It's a matter of interpretation :).

Comment: Thanks to all, If I want to remove the same pipe-delimiters. Howto do that?